# Дописать блоки в корзине Drupal

Tags: php, html, drupal

Нужно дописать пару блоков в корзине товаров Drupal UBERCAR, в каком файле можно дописать код?

Comment: в своем модуле хакать код модулей плохой тон. А вообще что за блоки может и писать ни чего не надо ?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно добавить на шаг /cart - то через:
`hook_tapir_table_alter`
или
`hook_form_alter` для `form_id = 'uc_cart_view_form'`.
Для шага /cart/checkout:
`hook_uc_cart_checkout_review` или `hook_form_uc_cart_checkout_form_alter` (сразу с указанием формы, например, как альтернатива первому варианту)